# Ionic 3 - How to prevent the user from clicking slide pager from slide 0 to slide 2 if slide 1 is not answered

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on a Ionic 3 questionnaire application where the user cannot go from one slide to another until the question is answered on a slide. I got everything working except pager (this dots) is allowing the user to go from one slide to another even though question# 2 is not answered.

I added the following logic but its not working as expected. Its still allowing me to jump from slide 0 to slide 2. Adding `this.slideTo(this.currentIndex)` changed the dot to be highlighted for slide 0 however its showing the contents of Slide# 2.

```
onSlideWillChange(event) {
    let answerNotSelected: boolean = false;
    for (let i: number = 0; i < this.slides.getActiveIndex(); i++) {
      answerNotSelected = this.questionnaire.questions[i].selectedAnswer === undefined;
      if (answerNotSelected) { 
        console.log('Returning from newQuestionIndex ' + this.slides.getActiveIndex() +  ' to current slide:' + this.currentQuestionIndex);
        this.slideTo(this.currentQuestionIndex);
      }
    }  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just lock the slides, and only enable back when the question has an answer. That way, the pager won't change the current slide (It would just be there to give the user some feedback about how many other questions are there in the questionnaire):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true); // Lock the slides
  }

  public showPrevious(): void {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false); // Unlock the slides
    this.slides.slidePrev(500);    // Move the the previous
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);  // Lock the slides again
  }

  public showNext(): void {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false); // Unlock the slides
    this.slides.slideNext(500);    // Move the the next
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);  // Lock the slides again
  }
}
```

Please take a look at this **[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uybKEFkZz2a9bGEmyd49?p=preview)** for a demo.

Comment: Thanks! But, the designer does not want previous and next buttons. He wants it such that on making a selection it automatically takes the user to next slide and on clicking back-button chevron (on desktop), they can navigate to previous slide or by clicking pager/swiping. The above is working as expected. I changed ionSlideWillChange to ionSlideNextStart and if answer is not selected I tried event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() to stop the event but I get an error preventDefault is not a function or stopPropagation is not function. How do I stop the ionic events?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - for anyone in the future I solved it in a albeit slightly hacky way (since _paginationContainer is an internal variable). You could probably also as easily just find elements in the DOM.

I called this on

> ionSlideWillChange

, but it could probably be called on any of the swipe events.

ion-slide is very poorly documented, but it is based off of http://idangero.us/swiper/api/ and has all the same methods so you can look here for better documentation.

```
lockAll() {
    var current = this.slider.getActiveIndex();
    let array = this.slider._paginationContainer.childNodes
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      var button : any = array[index];
      if (this.inRange(index, current -1, current +1)) {
        button.disabled = false;
      }
      else {
        button.disabled = true
      }
    }
}

inRange(x, min, max) {
    return ((x-min)*(x-max) <= 0);
}
```